# Height of UIScrollView get changed?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am adding `UITableView` and `UIButton` in `UIScrollView`. button is placed below tableview.

Well, when i select any row from table it add a button on that row and every thing is ok till now, but when i click that row second time it remove button added on it but the problem is that along with removing that button it also scroll my table up and button bellow the table reside on its place ie. it leaves gap between table and button. 
my table is reloaded every time when a row is clicked.
code for add `UIButton`below the `UITableView`

```
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        mainTable.frame = CGRectMake(mainTable.frame.origin.x, mainTable.frame.origin.y,
                                      mainTable.frame.size.width,
                                      ([menuItemsArray count] * 60) + 380);

        [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,([menuItemsArray count] * 60) + 80 + 350)];

        reserverBtnBottom = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [reserverBtnBottom setFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f,mainTable.frame.size.height,280, 40)];
        [reserverBtnBottom addTarget:self action:@selector(reserveBtnAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [reserverBtnBottom setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [reserverBtnBottom setAlpha:1];
        [reserverBtnBottom setTitle:@"Reserve this table" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [reserverBtnBottom setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [scrollView addSubview:reserverBtnBottom];
rest thing goes here
}
```

What am i missing?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you perform the layout to keep the button below the table of dynamic height ? To make it simpler you can use the table footer view, that's an alternative, not an answer.

Comment: @A-Live i'm setting frame of button and giving y-coordinate equals to height of table.

Comment: Where do you set the button's frame ?

Comment: in heightForRowAtIndexPath method, i've edited question please check.

Comment: @A-Live I've added button in table footer view, now table scrolled up along with button?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, did you try it and found the scrolling behavior incorrect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long time i resolve my problem. put this code in `viewWillAppear` instead `heightForRowAtIndexPath`-

```
mainTable.frame = CGRectMake(mainTable.frame.origin.x, mainTable.frame.origin.y,
                                      mainTable.frame.size.width,
                                      ([menuItemsArray count] * 60) + 380);

        [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,([menuItemsArray count] * 60) + 80 + 350)];
```

and move my reserveBtnBottom to footer of UITableView.

Thanks to **A-Live** for his great help.

Answer (score 0):

`heightForRowAtIndexPath` is a bad place for such calculation, as you are changing a single row state this method might be called once to calculate the new height. When it is called the cell still has an old height value, so does the table.

The button position calculation should be moved to `layoutSubviews:` method of the table and button **superview** which is a scrollView in your example. The way it should work is that the superview recalculates all the subviews frames once any of them changes it's frame.

Sometimes instead of overriding the `layoutSubviews:` the frame calculation is handled with the `viewController` , that's what you were trying to do but you did it in a wrong way. You'll need to find a better place for the frame calculation if you don't want to override scrollView `layoutSubviews:`.

If you only need the scrollView to add the button below the table, it would be better from my experience to get rid of the scroll view (at least because you do have scroll view in another scroll view which is Never a good practice) and add the button to the table footerView. The footer view is displayed below the table and scrolls together with it.

Comment: yes i did that, but problem is that when i select a row table is scrolled up and leave some space at bottom and its happen when i click second time on row, on first click it is working fine(note that second time doesn't mean double click)

Comment: Do you change the cell height on selection/deselection ? Why is there no returned value at `heightForRowAtIndexPath` ?

Comment: No i do not change cell height on selection/deselection and i'm returning cell height from heightForRowAtIndexPath.